# unordered_map with values of containers holding different trivial types

Tags: c++

I am trying to make an entity component system with an interface like so:

```
int main() {
    ecs::Registry registry;

    // Add int, float, double components to the registry
    registry.createComponents<int, float, double>();
    
    // You don't have to supply all of the components at once
    registry.createComponents<char>();

    // Create an entity with int and float components, initialize them to 1 and 1.3f
    ecs::Entity entity = registry.createEntity<int, float>(1, 1.3f);

    // Add a double and a char component to the entity, set the double to 4.8
    entity.addComponents<double, char>(4.8);

    // Set the char component of entity to 'a'
    // You don't have to set all the components in the addComponents function. Components not set will be default initialized
    entity.set<char>('a');

    // Access a component with entity.get<Component>()
    std::cout << entity.get<int>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << entity.get<float>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << entity.get<double>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << entity.get<char>() << std::endl;

    // Remove given components
    entity.removeComponents<int, float, double>();

    // Print number of components
    std::cout << "number of components: " << entity.componentCount() << std::endl;

    // Char component still valid after other components deleted
    std::cout << entity.get<char>() << std::endl;

    // Delete entity
    registry.deleteEntity(entity);

    // Remove all given components from the registry
    registry.deleteComponents<int, float, double, char>();
}
```

The `Registry` holds all the data, `Entity` merely holds its ID and a reference to the `Registry`. The problem is, inside the `Registry`, I want to have arrays of `int`s, `float`s, `double`s, basically any trivial type. And I want to be able to access them through templated functions, and the only way I can envision this system working is by having an `unordered_map` with keys of `type_index` and `vector`s of the type specified by the `type_index`. But I can't have an `unordered_map` with differently templated values. I made a really dumb class that goes against every good C++ practice you could follow that would just hold the types using a `vector` of `uint8_t`s, but that is.. bad. Not good. Very messy code and an interface that makes me want to cry.

How do I have an `unordered_map` that holds *contiguous*, *homogeneous* containers of different *trivial* types?

Comment: Just so it's clear; the sample code I have compiles and runs with the code I already have. This isn't a fanciful, impossible exercise. But my library as it stands is built with twigs. A light breeze half way across the planet will cause this thing to segfault.

Comment: It sounds as if you want a vector of `std::variant<int, double,...>`. Variants are the way to go to hold different types and access them via templated functions.

Comment: `variant` doesn't work well for this, considering it's a library where the user will define what types to use, and the user can add/remove types from the `Registry`'s component pool over the course of their program.

Comment: Maybe `std::unordered_map<type_index. std::any>`? It will work with non-trivial types as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold each type in a separate unordered_map. That way you can support any data type.
Here's a possible implementation of Registry and Entity classes:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <memory>

struct icontainer
{
    virtual ~icontainer() = default;
};
template <typename T>
struct container : icontainer
{
  
    std::unordered_map<int, //entry_id
        T> m_entryIdToValue; //value
};
struct Entity;

struct Registry
{
    template <typename First>
    void createComponents()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<icontainer> up{ new container<First> };
        m_registeredContainers[std::type_index(typeid(First))] = std::move(up);
    }

    template <typename First, typename Second, typename... Types>
    void createComponents()
    {
        createComponents<First>();
        createComponents<Second, Types...>();
    }

    template <typename... Types>
    Entity createEntity(Types ...values);

    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<icontainer>> m_registeredContainers;
    std::size_t m_entityId = 0;
};

struct Entity
{
     Entity(Registry *registry, std::size_t id) :m_registry(registry), m_nId(id){}

    template <typename First>
    void addComponents(const First &value)
    {
        get<First>() = value;
    }

    template <typename First, typename Second, typename... Types >
    void addComponents(const First& first_value, const Second& second_value, Types ...values)
    {
        addComponents<First>(first_value);
        addComponents<Second, Types...>(second_value, values...);
    }

    template <typename T>
    T& get()
    {
        icontainer& c = *m_registry->m_registeredContainers[std::type_index(typeid(T))];
        return static_cast<container<T>*>(&c)->m_entryIdToValue[m_nId];
    }

    std::size_t m_nId = 0;
    Registry* m_registry = nullptr;
};

template <typename... Types>
Entity Registry::createEntity(Types ...values)
{
    Entity e(this, m_entityId++);
    e.addComponents(std::forward<Types>(values)...);
    return e;
}
```

Here's a creation of 2 entities from a repository:

```
int main()
{
    Registry r;
    r.createComponents<int,float,double,char>();
    Entity e = r.createEntity<int, float>(1,1.1f);
    e.addComponents<double>(2.2);

    std::cout << "entity 1 int " << e.get<int>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "entity 1 float " << e.get<float>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "entity 1 double " << e.get<double>() << std::endl;

    Entity e2 = r.createEntity<int, char>(5, 'A');
    std::cout << "entity 2 int " << e2.get<int>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "entity 2 char " << e2.get<char>() << std::endl;


    return 0;
  
}
```

**Output:**

entity 1 int 1

entity 1 float 1.1

entity 1 double 2.2

entity 2 int 5

entity 2 char A

- The code was compiled and tested on Visual Studio 2019.